# Почему в русском языке японские названия переведены с 'си' там, где в японском 'ши' или 'щи'

Tags: перевод

Конкретные примеры: "Хиросима", "Кагосима", "Сикоку". На Википедии даже в произношении показывает с, хотя в японском используется звук 'щ'? (Возможно спорить про ш или щ, но щ намного ближе к действительности, по-моему)

Откуда появился такой стандарт перевода?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Вы же понимаете, что собственные имена не *переводят*, их либо [транскрибируют](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), либо [транслитерируют](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). В случае японского языка речь идёт как раз о *транслитерации*, а именно, транслитерации русскими буквами того, как японские собственные имёна записываются японской слоговой азбукой [кана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0). Иными словами, русскими буквами передаются не японские *звуки* этих имён, а японские «*буквы*» (силабограммы), которыми эти имена пишутся в японском языке. Японская фонетика значительно отличается от русской, так что если бы мы пытались точно записать именно *звуки*, то русских букв бы явно не хватило и пришлось бы создавать громоздкую фонетичскую транскрипцию на основе русских букв, которую каждому пришлось бы специально изучать. Поэтому был выбран более простой путь — транслитерация. Немного не точная передача японских звуков, зато каждый может прочитать, не нужно вводить дополнительные специальные буквы, не требуется специального обучения.

Современный стандарт транслитерации японского русскими буквами – это так называемая [система Поливанова](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0), разработанная российским востоковедом Евгением Дмитриевичем Поливановым в 1917 году.

Должен обратить ваше внимание, что как ни крути, ни одна из русских букв не передаёт японский звук [ɕ] «лучше», чем другая: <с> это [s], <ш> это [ʂ]. Но вот <щ> — это [ɕː], и он ничем не лучше двух предыдущих, так как он долгий, а японский [ɕ] — краткий. Японский звук [ɕ] ([описание и аудио](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%82)) – это именно тот, что в заголовке вопроса. К вашему сведению, «Сикоку», 四国, произносится [ɕiko̞kɯ̟ᵝ], то есть в нём нет не только <с> или <щ>, но нет и <у> (в японском <у> вообще нет).

И заметьте, «Хиросима», «Кагосима», «Сикоку» — это *русские* слова, хоть и японского происхождения, следовательно в них не может быть никаких иных звуков, кроме как русских. Точно так же как *Paris*, который по-французски называется «Пари», на русском – Париж.

Comment: Спасибо, искал именно информацию про Поливанова. Одно непонятно, неужели разница [ɕː] и [ɕ] сравнима с [s] и [ɕ]? Вопрос первоначально был от жены - она учит русский, и удивилась, что по-русски часто используется "с", хотя её слуху ближе "щ" или "ш" (мы в этом дилетанты, простите если дурацкий вопрос). Но ещё более непонятно теперь, почему ち у Поливанова превращается в "ти", ведь ち и "ч" - это tɕ?

Comment: @Kolichikov - Поскольку у нас тут Russian Language SE, то я не стал вдаваться в подробности. Суть: в японском различаются долгие и краткие согласные, есть [ɕ] и есть [ɕː]. Рская буква <С> обозначет [ɕ] _только_ перед <И>, <Ё>, <Ю>, <Я>, то есть когда в русском перед этими буквами она читается как мягкая <СЬ> [sʲ]. Так вот именно этот [sʲ] и является условным обозначением японского [ɕ], поскольку [ɕ] — это аллофон япон. фонемы /s/ перед /i/ и т.п., он же в ряду S в кане и стоит, т.е. в системе Поливанова всё логично. Японская фонология и фонетика — _очень_ запутанная штука.

Comment: Причём тут "собственные имена", когда поливановцы обычно настаивают на произношении любых слов в соответствии с транслитерацией? Что самое забавное, что они сами же и забывают почему то что это только транслитерация, место которой в учебных материалах.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov - Кто такие «поливановцы», где они на таком настаивают, и какое нам до них дело тут, на Russian Language SE?

Comment: @YellowSky "кто такие поливановцы?" под ответом целиком посвящённым пропаганде Поливанова в безапелляционном тоне? Серьёзно? Я ожидал диалога с собеседником более высокого уровня.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov - Пропаганда?)) Я вам задал вопросы в ожидании ответов. Вы что, любитель манги и аниме, уязвленный тем, что другие пишут тамошние слова не так, как _вам слышится_? Ожидали диалога? Так я же его и начал, задал вопросы, так и отвечайте по существу.

Comment: @YellowSky я бы мог обойтись LMGTFY на "поливановцы", ну да ладно, разок поведусь: "поливановцы" - фанаты транскрипции Поливанова, которые упорно ведут борьбу за её исключительное использование везде, а не только в учебных и справочных материалах, абсолютно игнорируя что средний человек тут же начнёт читать транслитерацию по правилам русского языка, на что она в некоторых местах не рассчитана. Где они настаивают? В этом ответе. Какое нам дело? Этот ответ именно на RL.SE.

Comment: @YellowSky про аниме и мангу, напоминаю, что про ad hominem я уже сказал. Демагогию держите при себе. В своей наивной попытке уязвить меня вы немного упустили что в манге произношения нет вообще за отсутствием любого вокала и что услышать японскую речь можно не только в аниме.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov - А что, это плохо, если люди будут читать транслитерацию по правилам русского языка? Кто или что от этого пострадает? Вот лично я плевать хотел на то, как в русском записываются японские слова — ниндзя, нинджя, нинжя — мне похер, вы напрасно меня записали в «поливановцы» и начали спорить, по сути, с самим собой. Я просто хочу понять противника старой доброй, хорошо зарекомендовавшей себя системы транслитерации. Ну вот какое вам до неё дело? Чем она вам не угодила?

Comment: @YellowSky Как вы думаете, почему "лет ме спик фром май харт" стало мемом? Необдуманная поливанщина вызывает такой же эффект. Повторяю раз в третий (? не считал): я не имею ничего против транслитерации, там где транслитерации место.

Comment: Не путайте божий дар с яичницей. Одно дело, когда плохо говорят на иностранном языке, другое дело, когда иностранные имена да и слова вообще входят в язык в искаженном виде. Вы что, смеётесь? Вы не знаете, как японцы коверкают заимствования из английского? Например: ブレザー буредза: — 'blazer' — блейзер; デリバリーヘルス дерибари: херусу — 'delivery health' — проститутка, и т.п. Или вы такой перфекционист, что говорите «Акэнсó», «Хадсн», «Póбинсн» вместо дурацких транслитерационных прочтений «Арканзас», «Гудзóн», «Робинзóн»?

Comment: Отрадно видеть, что дело "система Поливанова" vs. "как я на самом деле слышу" живёт и... нет, не побеждает, конечно - победа в этом святом деле невозможна - но живёт!

Comment: @Kolichikov В некоторых случаях происходит и транскрибирование. Скажем, название популярного стиля карате традиционно транскрибируется как "шотокан", а имя его основателя -- как "Фунакоши". Но при этом один из ударов транслитерируется как "моваси". Иногда говорят и "моваши", но чаще -- "моваси". Так повелось.

Answer (score 10):

В дополнение к ответу YellowSky приведу цитату из книги лингвиста [В.М.Алпатова](http://www.koob.pro/alpatov_v) ["Япония: язык и культура"](https://www.e-reading.club/book.php?book=136744) (кстати, книгу рекомендую всем, кто интересуется Японией):

> ..Следует учитывать и то, что среди разных видов латиницы, безусловно, и
> в Японии, и вне ее господствует самый традиционный. Это появившаяся
> еще в XIX в. так называемая латиница Xэпбёрна, ее автор, миссионер,
> был одним из первых американцев, изучивших японский язык. Она имеет
> много недостатков (прежде всего, она недостаточно научна) и всего одно
> достоинство: она хорошо **соответствует звуковым представлениям
> носителей английского, но не русского и, главное, не японского языка**.
>
> И в русском, и в японском языке очень развито противопоставление
> твердых и мягких согласных, которого нет в английском языке.
> Американцы и англичане воспринимают японские мягкие с', т\ дз' как ш,
> ч, дж (графически sh, ch, j), а прочие мягкие -- как сочетания с йотом:
> скажем, слог k'a воспринимается как kya.
>
> Отметим, что русская
> кириллическая **транскрипция, разработанная Е. Д. Поливановым, основана
> на иных, более научных принципах**, и поэтому русские написания вроде
> суши, Хитачи, а не суси, Хитати показывают, что эти слова взяты либо
> из японских текстов на латинице, либо (что во много раз вероятнее) из
> английского, а не японского языка. Еще в БЯРС (2, 165) и как японское
> слово, и как его русский эквивалент дается не суши, а суси, но сейчас
> так, кажется, говорят только профессиональные японисты. С этим трудно
> бороться, если английский язык известен в России намного лучше
> японского. ...

Comment: И что это за "научные принципы" кроме личной любви автора к Поливановщине?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov - Вы что, разбираетесь в принципах японской фонетики? У вас, верно, есть свой собсвенный, глубоконаучно обоснованный взгляд на то, как _надо_ японские слова _правильно_ транслитерировать русскими буквами? Или вы за то, чтобы оставлять их в русском тексте без изменения, так, как они пишутся по-японски?

Comment: @YellowSky аргумент "сначала добейся!" оставьте демагогам. К вопросу о фонетике я проводил достаточно большие (насколько это может сделать один человек) опросы среди разнообразных слоёв населения, какие слоги они слышат в диалоге/песне. К ответам не подталкивал - не было списков для выбора, ответ давался исключительно опрошенным. "си"/"ти" оказались в глубоком конце списка.

Comment: И таки да, что же всё-таки за таинственные принципы? Само выражение "более научные" уже как-то подозрительно звучит. Не сьезжайте на личность вопрошающего - ad hominem из того же списка.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov - Т.е. вы опрашивали носителей одного языка насчет того, какие слоги они слышат в другом, им незнакомом языке? По-вашему, в таком опросе может быть какая-то научная ценность? Какая?

Comment: Очевидно: узнать как слоги "незнакомого языка" приемлемее для правильного восприятия записывать для носителей "одного языка".

Comment: У кого это ещё узнавать как не у носителей? Напоминаю, что в случае языков академия в основном фиксирует норму, а не вводит её.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov - А вы не проводили опрос среди рускоязычных о том, насколько им важно, чтобы японские слова в русском языке записывались максимально точно? Вот взять среднестатистических молодых людей, им это, думаете, важно?

Comment: Я правильно понял что этот вопрос подразумевает "мы записываем не точно, но это не важно, потому что нас некому ловить"? QED, как бы. Впрочем я ничего не имею против использования Поливанова самого по себе. Если вы перечитаете мои первые комментарии к вашему и к этому вопросу, они задают конкретные вопросы к конкретным спорным местам в соответствующих ответах.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov - Ну, на ваш вопрос о научных принципах я могу дать ответ, вот он: [Грамматика японского языка. Введение, фонология, супрафонология, морфонология (2000, Алпатов, Вардуль, Старостин)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sPsh2Rs5OdxEGBqwG8endo-RSqwOJuck/view?usp=sharing). Прочитав эту замечательную и совсем недлинную (150 стр.) книжечку, вы будете знать о японской фонологии и фонетике **всё**. Прочитайте, и, я уверен, тогда вам больше не захочется нигде писать такое, что вы тут понаписывали. Всего хорошего.

Comment: Товарищ, ты когда-нибудь про своё "сначала добейся" и прочее давление авторитетом забудешь? Советую - без этого аргументации не будет. Вопрос о звучании одного слога легко в лезет в параграф, максимум два. Или приведи их здесь, или оставь своё потрясение авторитетами при себе. Правило о том что "link only answers" не катит - придумали как раз для такого.

Answer (score 0):

Тот самый звук, с которым все маятся ближе всего по звучанию в русском языке именно к Щ. Только вот тот звук, который мы используем, длинный, а у японцев он короткий. Из-за короткости звука его легко можно воспринять за мягкий С. Можно было также транслетировать как Ш+мягкий согласный, но из-за правил русского мы бы всё равно это читали бы это как твёрдое Ш+твёрдый согласный, максимум бы просто превратили бы Ш в долгое Щ. Поэтому Поливанов скорее всего решил транслитировать с помощью С. Похожая проблема с Дз и J. У японцев там на деле Д+Мягкая Ж, этот звук конечно в русском языке присутствует, но редко и имеет форму долготы в произношении, и единственное, что передаёт этот мягкий звук, это псевдодиграф ЗЖ. Тогда бы получилось у нас Ниндзжя, Фудзжияма и Кодзжима. Что как бы затрудняет чтение и восприятие иероглифов.

Answer (score 0):

В системе Поливанова дело совсем не в звуках, а в стандартной транслитерации.

Потому, что в японском - さしすせそ, в этой системе тоже - са,**си**,су,се,со.

Есть и исключение. В японском - たちつてと, а здесь - та,**ти**,***цу***,те,то.

Answer (score -1):

Как уже сказано в других ответах, так пишется из-за транскрипции Поливанова. Она удобна и однозначна в учебных материалах. Студент, который читает "хитати", понимает что имеется ввиду хи=ひ, та=た и ти=ち и что это надо произносить именно так как произносятся японские слоги, а не как русские буквы.

Почему она используется за их пределами? Единственный ответ: "так повелось". Никаких "научных" принципов использовать транслитерацию в ***произношении*** нет.

Можно сколько угодно распинаться о единственно православном кунрее и ссылаться на Поливанова, забывая что мало того что он создал именно транслитерацию, т.е. метод записи, а не произношения, так он ещё и основывался на вполне определённом произношении всего одного из регионов и делал это более века назад. Но практика показывает, что японцы сами прекрасно осведомлены о неоднозначности слогов し и ち, которые далеки от "си" и "ти" и, поэтому в наше время всё чаще используют новые комбинации для передачи иностранных слов чтобы показать однозначное "ти" - в основном в катакане.

- realty = リアルティ
- community = コミュニティ
- safety - セーフティ
- milk tea - ミルクティー

Некоторые другие комбинации можно найти в Википедии:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_into_Japanese#Extended_katakana_2

Что следует использовать?

- Если вы пишете учебный материал - Поливанова. Читатель знает что с этим написанием делать.
- Если используются давно заимствованные слова - традиционный вариант. Токё: или нинжя вряд ли кто сразу распознает по сравнению с уже привычным Токио или ниндзя. (NB! Токио, к слову, из ещё более ранней системы транскрипции - так же как и Киото или джиу-джитсу, но я что-то не замечаю чтобы кто-то топил за эту систему только на основании старости и традиционности, а вот про Поливанова "так принято давно" говорят постоянно.)
- Если новые слова или имена из новых произведений и, при этом они являются японскими, а не заимствованными - как удобнее и как слышно. Умный поливановец знает, что это транскрипция и возмущаться не будет, а возмущением неумных можно пренебречь.

Answer (score -6):

К сожалению у русских больная тяга к транслитерации из-за чего в России Hideo Kojima зовут Кодзима вместо Коджима, а у меня в загран. паспорте вместо Yaroslav(Ярослав), написано Iaroslav, а Alexander(Александр) стал Aleksandr и т.д...
Этот вопрос очень большая проблема связанная, как мне кажется с невежеством. В прочем я могу ошибаться и в английском есть Godzilla, который Dojira, хотя это не столько имя, сколько интертеймент бренд, а бренды локализуют.

Comment: Так-таки прям вот по-японски бедолагу Hideo Kojima зовут? (Подсказка: прочитайте все же оба предыдущих ответа).

Comment: @Yaroslav пожалуйста, будьте сдержанней и относитесь к другим юзерам если не дружелюбно, так хотя бы неагрессивно.

Comment: @shabunc, я не называл его глупым, дураком или другим обидным словом. Я лишь назвал его "Так-таки" чепухой... и почему это чепуха. Не было никакой личностной агрессии, не гони!

Comment: Вспоминается анекдот, как мужичок приходит на прием к психиатру: — Доктор, со мной никто не хочет общаться! Не пойму почему! Может, ты, уродец, мне сможешь помочь?!

Comment: А почему Alexandr должен становиться Aleksander ? :> мало ли как там англичане имена переделывают/ли... :>

Comment: _Коджима — джиниэс_